# No shoot Sherlock: Test your internet and detective skills with this one!

Tags: story, computer-puzzle, geography, knowledge

**Clues**

I have hired Sherlock Holmes to find something for me. We are near my home at an outdoor event and queuing for the refreshment tent. I suspect that the object is to be found somewhere in this area.

Holmes: *So Mister Chasly, How can I be of assistance?*

Me: *Mr Holmes, you know I'm from near here. There's something I want you to find.*

We near the front of the queue. Dr Watson comes hurrying up and pushes in without asking.

Watson to Sherlock: *Tea Holmes?*

Sherlock to Watson: *Queue, Watson, there's a queue!*

Ignoring Watson, I give the famous detective a piece of paper.

Me: *I afraid that this is the only clue that I can provide.*

I hand Sherlock a piece of paper with some figures written on it.

Sherlock: *Hmm... 19852 05812*

Holmes screws up his eyes and appears to be concentrating hard. After a few moments he opens his eyes, turns and points.

Sherlock:  That way I think!

Forgetting about the refreshments, Holmes strides away. Watson and I follow behind. Soon we had found the thing I was seeking.

To those reading this puzzle - I wish I could show you a photograph of the object, I took one but but I have lost it. Can you make me a new one? I'd be most grateful.

**Question**

Provide a photograph of the man-made object that Holmes found for me. The photo can be from any angle as long as most of the object is clearly visible and discernible among any nearby vegetation.

NOTES

CodeNewbie has demonstrated that I wasn't quite specific enough. The object is smaller than the average house and bigger than a football (English type). It is roughly/partly spherical in shape.

On request from the community I have also removed the restriction that answerers should withhold their reasoning. Please do give your reasoning. Of course I would still appreciate if you could hide it by using the >! facility.

Note that this may be harder for some people because of where they live and therefore what they can be expected to know. They can still find all the information by using the clues but they may have to work a little harder and longer in order to find the extra knowledge.

You do not need a camera, just the internet.

Comment: Why are they so many downvotes on this one ?

Comment: @Therandomguy Probably because you are not allowed to post the method you used to discover the answer, but this is just my guess because [this meta questions](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/i-created-a-question-however-i-want-the-method-of-solving-to-continue-to-be-a-m#3237) (which is about the topic I mentioned before) also has a couple of downvotes.

Comment: "The object is smaller than the average house?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this the thing that you're after:

> [image]

Or, from another angle:

> [image]

Method:

> The discussion between Holmes and Watson mentions "Tea" and "Queue". Putting these together with the numbers and carrying out Google search for `TQ 19852 05812`, the first result (in the UK at least) is [Shoreham Airfield Information Exchange](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjAu7Wlm7DHAhVEOhQKHYKiDkk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.airfieldinformationexchange.org%2Fcommunity%2Fshowthread.php%3F3760-Shoreham&ei=SuDRVcDuMMT0UILFusgE&usg=AFQjCNEBAgTSQ1FrxGJgtQRx9vow5_kv3w&sig2=rZpCUSqDlBsfUPttU1T8LA&bvm=bv.99804247,d.bGQ) in which there is a discussion about this building. The setting for the question is an outdoor event which could quite easily be at the airfield.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed it!

Comment: @chasly from UK why not give away method..?

Comment: It's a very important part of Q&A sites. If you don't explain how you got your answer, it isn't a good answer.

Comment: @warspyking -  That is an interesting point. Maybe we should ask about this on Meta. I'll create a question there and let you know.

Comment: I've posted a meta question ---> http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3237/i-created-a-question-however-i-want-the-method-of-solving-to-continue-to-be

Comment: What even is this thing? Reverse image searches bring up nothing.

Comment: @tfitzger "*That will be the dome LAA trainer building ...*". But I can't tell you where I found this as long as the OP doesn't allow anyone to post the method. Although you can probably figure that out yourself easily.

Comment: You said "it would be difficult to lose the object" to the answer of CodeNewbie. Now I am quite interested how it is possible to lose this as an object.

Comment: @Doorknob I'm happy to post an explanation if it is agreed that the OP's request not post methods or hints is relaxed.

Comment: Okay - It looks like I'm outnumbered. Please go ahead and post your explanation. :-)

Comment: Wa Kai - In fact the object is not easily seen from the ground. Partly because it is relatively low lying and also because the coloours camouflage it well against the surrounding vegetation. There are no signposts that point to it. This is in contrast to an airfield which has plenty of signage.

Comment: Note. I forgot that Google would bypass some of the clever stuff that would otherwise be needed to solve it. Nevertheless you got the correct answer and I have no complaints. P.S. The setting just has to be the UK it doesn't have to be the airport although the fact that Holmes walked there makes it seem likely.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Shoreham airfield _again_?!

Comment: @randal'thor - I was determined to get a valid question out of it. The last one was stomped on!

Comment: @chaslyfromUK OMFG, better stop making puzzles out of Shoreham airfield - you've [jinxed](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-34027260) it! :-O

Answer (score 1):

Is this the image you are looking for?

> [image]It is Britain's first licensed aerodrome. And since you are [chasly from UK](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14177/chasly-from-uk), this would be quite close to you.

Comment: I think it's not, because I'm sure Chasly would check that you don't need to just google search the numbers :P Also, it's an object. (Maybe that would fall into that category though)

Comment: @LuxxMiner: I am certain this is exactly the answer he wants. I can string along all the clues he's provided inside the story. But I've chosen to honor his desire to not explain my method.

Comment: @LuxxMiner: Also, "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth." :P

Comment: @CodeNewbie - Yes Mr Holmes. I should have been more specific.

Comment: I feel bad because someone else has now got it and I added extra constraints since you answered. I think I can eliminate your answer  because it would be difficult to lose the object you showed. Especially if you were within walking distance!  I'm open to discussion though!